# VS2017 [15.8.6] if constexpr build error with C2760 message

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2017, c++17, variant

Since the latest release of VS2017, this code doesn't work while same code build fine in previous release :

```
inline std::tuple<float, float> _convertCentsToAlterAndCents (float shift);

using AccidentalVar = std::variant<std::nullopt_t, int, float, double, const char*, std::string, Accidental, Accidental::Ptr>;

void Pitch::accidental(AccidentalVar value)
{
    std::visit([this](auto&& arg)
    {
        using T = std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(arg)>>;

        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int> ||
                      std::is_same_v<T, float> || 
                      std::is_same_v<T, double>)
        {
            auto [alter, cents] = _convertCentsToAlterAndCents(static_cast<float>(arg) * 100.f);
            _accidental = std::make_shared<Accidental>(alter);
            if (abs(cents) > 0.01f)
                microtone(cents);
        }
        else
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, const char*> ||
                      std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)
        {
            _accidental = std::make_shared<Accidental>(arg);
        }
        else
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Accidental::Ptr>)
        {
            _accidental = (arg != nullptr) ? arg->deepcopy() : arg;
        }
        else
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Accidental>)
        {
            _accidental = arg.deepcopy();
        }
        else
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::nullopt_t>)
        {
            _accidental = nullptr;
        }
    },
    value);
}
```

The error is `C2760, unexcepted token '>'` in the `if (abs(cents) > 0.01f)` line.

If I remove the `constexpr` in the `if constexpr`, I get a `static_cast<float>` problem because the `arg (std::variant)` can be a `std::nullopt` (further processed in the visitor).

Why the simple condition `abs(cents) > 0.01f` failed to build?

Thank you very much for your answer.

**EDIT:**

Maybe my problem is related to this :

**constexpr**

Visual Studio 2017 correctly raises an error when the left-hand operand of a conditionally evaluating operation is not valid in a constexpr context. The following code compiles in Visual Studio 2015 but not in Visual Studio 2017 (C3615 constexpr function 'f' cannot result in a constant expression):

```
template<int N>
struct array
{
    int size() const { return N; }
};

constexpr bool f(const array<1> &arr)
{
    return arr.size() == 10 || arr.size() == 11; // C3615
}
```

To correct the error, either declare the array::size() function as constexpr or remove the constexpr qualifier from f.

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/cpp/cpp-conformance-improvements-2017?view=vs-2017#bug-fixes-in-visual-studio-versions-150-153update153-155update155-157update157-and-158update158

**EDIT2:**
If I comment the line `if (abs(cents) > 0.01f)` (call `microtone(cents)` without threshold condition), the code build fine. So, while `0.01f` is a `float constant`, and `cents` is a `float temporary variable`, the only problem come from the call to the `std::abs` function. As I see `std::abs` is not a constexpr function.

How to resolve this point without write a internal version of std::abs that is constexpr valid?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I can't, my project is too large to provide the complete code.

Comment: The only thing I can explain is : 1/ the code compile fine with previous VS2017 release < 15.8.6 ... 2/ when I remove the constexpr in the if constexpr condition, this error disappear but I have another problem with the variant while the static_cast can't build with the arg that can be a std::nullopt.

Comment: I guess VS 2017 don't provide support to c++17 yet, hence std::variant should not compile.

Comment: seccpur - wrong. VS2017 support C++14 / C++17 and experimental code for further C++ release (ex. co-routine ...).

Comment: side note: `remove_cv` and `remove_reference`  together is usually spelled `decay`

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen MS Developer bug report https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/323938/broken-parsing-of-greater-than-comparison-operator.html

The bug above seems to be fixed in the 2019 Preview.
But until then as noted in the bug report.

Minimizing the above code to reproduce the error in vs 2017 follows.
The fix is notated in the sequence of visit...; if constexpr (...; if (... > ....) expression by surrounding ()s or reversing logic of > operator
Note: the ">" after the visit; if constexpr sequence can cause problem in other situations.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <variant>
#include <optional>

inline std::tuple<float, float> _convertCentsToAlterAndCents(float shift)
{ 
    return std::tuple{shift, shift};
}
//using AccidentalVar = std::variant<std::nullopt_t, int, float, double, const char*, std::string, Accidental, Accidental::Ptr>;
using AccidentalVar = std::variant<std::nullopt_t, int, float, double, const char*>;

void microtone(float cents) {} 

//void Pitch::accidental(AccidentalVar value)
void test(AccidentalVar value)
{
    //std::visit([this](auto&& arg)
    std::visit([&](auto&& arg)
    {
        using T = std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(arg)>>;

        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int> ||
            std::is_same_v<T, float> ||
            std::is_same_v<T, double>)
        {
            auto[alter, cents] = _convertCentsToAlterAndCents(static_cast<float>(arg) * 100.f);
            //_accidental = std::make_shared<Accidental>(alter);

            //if (abs(cents) > 0.01f) // error in vs 2017
            if ( ( abs(cents) > 0.01f ) ) // FIX 1 or
            //if( 0.01f <= abs(cents) ) // or FIX 2
                microtone(cents);
        }
        // remaining code removed...
    },
    value);
}
```